# Qt Application fails spectacularly

Tags: qt, reference, g++, mingw, undefined

I'm trying to link a Qt application with its libraries and the linker (MinGW) spews hundreds of lines like the following, and I am unsure how to proceed.

```
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
 c:/qt/lib/libQtCore.a(qcoreapplication_win.o)(.text+0x29d):qcoreapplication_win.
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
 c:/qt/lib/libQtCore.a(qcoreapplication_win.o)(.text+0x38c):qcoreapplication_win.
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
 c:/qt/lib/libQtCore.a(qcoreapplication_win.o)(.text+0x4ce):qcoreapplication_win.
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
 c:/qt/lib/libQtCore.a(qcoreapplication_win.o)(.text+0x53e):qcoreapplication_win.
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
 c:/qt/lib/libQtCore.a(qcoreapplication_win.o)(.text+0x635):qcoreapplication_win.
 cpp: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know... but to me, spewing stuff about Unwind suggests that you have a mismatch between whether the library is compiled with exceptions and your application is compiled with exceptions.

If you want exceptions, make sure you have enabled them by adding the following line in your qmake file:

```
CONFIG += exceptions
```

or, if you do not want exceptions, use the opposite

```
CONFIG -= exceptions
```

And whatever you do, do not use C++ compiler options to set this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did any Qt development, but there were only a couple instances that I remember spewing out huge numbers of messages like this.

- Include files for Qt were a
  different version than the shared
  libraries ... this happened when I
  upgraded and for some reason, you
  had to manually upgrade the include
  files.
- The Qt libraries were missing altogether ... I vaguely remember the compiler working, but the linker failing when I first started.

I was doing Qt development targeted at an ARM processor, so I had extra oddities involved when cross-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible reasons that i know of:

1. if you try to link gcc4 libraries with a gcc3 linker.
2. You need the `-lstdc++` flag to the end of the compile command